# How to get data from MongoDB in python when i have multiple epoch time in a list?

Tags: python, mongodb, time-series

I have epoch time in a list in python. How do I get the data from mongodb for all time present in a list? I tried to loop the query for all the time value, but I guess this slows down the execution.

```
time_list = [1553595310878, 1553595190830, 1553594831594, 1553594471976, 
                 1553593151893, 1553593030752,1553592432641,1553591952041, 
                 1553591893229, 1553591412779, 1553589791651]
client = MongoClient(host='ip', port=no,   username='*****', 
password='*****', authSource='****')
db=client.admin

list1 = [] 
list2 = []
list3 = []

for x in time_list:
     data=db.collectionname.find({"projectId":"122333333444","page.time":{'$eq':x}})
     for y in data:
         list1_end.append(pd.DataFrame(y['page'], index = [0])['pageLoad'].values.tolist())
         list2_end.append(pd.DataFrame(y['page'], index = [0])['dom'].values.tolist())
         list3_end.append(pd.DataFrame(y['page'], index = [0])['network'].values.tolist())

print(list1)
print(len(list1))
print(list2)
print(list3)
```

output is as below :

```
[[6278], [9032], [6358], [5066], [6886], [4449], [5597], [8332], [4634], [5902], [5803]]
11
[[3344], [2630], [3281], [2272], [3969], [2001], [3171], [5702], [2266], [2915], [2761]]
[[1165], [1399], [1259], [1278], [1245], [969], [1149], [1262], [818], [1684], [1262]]
```

Any output is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what you are looking for is the [MongoDB $in operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/). Its not guaranteed to improve speed though, but the only way to know will be to test.

In your case it will look something like this:

```
data=db.collectionname.find({"projectId":"122333333444","page.time":{'$in': time_list}})
```

Comment: thank you! i see great difference  before this Duration was: 0:00:04.467079 , after this  Duration: 0:00:02.237871

Comment: To be fair, its only a 2x improvement, but I'm glad it helped. ;-)